# Numpy: How to avoid rounding errors

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

I think I have a problem with Numpy and small numbers.

Can you help me finding a solution for the following problem:

```
import numpy as np

def gaussian(xx, mu=0, sigma=1):
    return 1./(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp(-(mu-xx)**2/(2*sigma**2))

factors = (1., 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001)
for factor in factors:
    xx = np.linspace(5000, 5200, 1000)
    yy = 1.-(factor*xx*(1.+gaussian(xx, 5100)))
    step = xx[1] - xx[0]

    print np.sum((1.-yy/(1.-factor*xx))*step)
```

This code should evaluate to `-1` for all of the different `factors`.
But the output is :

```
1.0 -1.00019611689
0.1 -1.00196463662
0.01 -1.0200000008
0.001 -1.24390245353
0.0001 1.04081641153
```

So the problem is, that the smaller the factor is, the more I get into trouble because of what I think has to do with the precision of Numpy/Python.

What to do to evaluate the equation even for the small factors?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: I suspect that at least part of the issue is in the mathematics (or, more probably, in the translation of the mathematics to Python + NumPy code).  Why do you think this should evaluate to -1?  What's this based on?

Comment: Rewrite the `yy`-part to `1-ax(1+g(x))` and the then part inside the sum to `1-yy/(1-ax) = 1-((1-ax(1+g(x))/(1-ax)) = 1-(1+g(x)) = -g(x)`. Since `g(x)` is a gaussian which has its peak at `5100` and a stddev of `1` and we are integrating over a range of `200` (from `5000` to `5200`) the `g(x)` will be 1 and thus the result will be `-1`. I think the mathematics is not the problem but the way Numpy/Python deals with the small numbers.

Comment: Nope: there's an error in your algebra.  Your expression simplifies to `axg(x) / (1 - ax)`, not to `-g(x)`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to define `yy` as `(1 - factor*xx)*(1+gaussian(xx, 5100))` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. When doing that the problem is solved and everything works fine. I tried to simplify a problem I had getting the code above. Obviously something went wrong. I need to check where I made the mistake ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a NumPy issue.  Your expectation that the result should be `-1` is incorrect.

You're effectively computing the definite integral of a function `f(x)` on a large interval around `5100`.  The function you're integrating simplifies to `factor * x * gaussian(x) / (1 - factor * x)`.  We can easily give a back-of-the-envelope estimate for the value of the integral for the factors you're using:  the quantity `factor * x / (1 - factor * x)` will vary fairly slowly across the range of interest, which is about `5095` to `5105`;  for anything outside this range the gaussian will render the contribution negligible.  So to a first approximation we can treat that quantity as constant.  Then we're left with that constant times the integral of `gaussian(x)`, which will be near enough `1`.  Thus the expected output should be somewhere in the region of `factor * 5100 / (1 - factor * 5100)`.  (Though that's not going to work so well when `factor` is close to `1 / 5100`.)

So for example in the case that `factor` is `0.0001`,  `factor * 5100 / (1 - factor * 5100)` has value around `1.0408163265306123`.  This is close enough to the answer you're seeing to make it plausible that NumPy is doing more-or-less the right thing.

Comment: Yeah, you are perfectly correct. I wanted to simplify a problem I had and made the mistake you described above. I am really sorry about that and although I have checked my simplification I messed it up. Thanks for your effort. Shame on me and upvotes for your correction.